# Key bindings broken in tmux 2.1

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, iterm2

I have the following lines in my `tmux.conf`:

```
bind C-n next-window
bind C-p previous-window
```

Then I have the following key mappings in ITerm2, which send send `C-f C-p` and `C-f C-n` to the terminal (my tmux prefix is `C-f`):

- <kbd>⌘ [</kbd>: `0x06 0x70`
- <kbd>⌘ ]</kbd>: `0x06 0x6e`

These mappings worked fine until I upgraded tmux from version 2.0 to version 2.1.

Now, the order in which tmux receives the keys seems to be reversed.  For example, running `cat` and then typing <kbd>⌘ [</kbd><kbd>ctrl f</kbd> produces the following:

```
$ cat
p^F
```

...while I would expect <kbd>⌘ [</kbd> to change the window.  Manually typing <kbd>ctrl f</kbd><kbd>ctrl p</kbd> works as expected.  If I connect to a remote machine running tmux 2.0, my key mappings work as they used to.

I don't understand why the binding works when I type it myself, but not when ITerm2 sends it.  Why would this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the `assume-paste-time` option in tmux to `0`.  It's not clear to me why this is needed since version 2.1, though (the default is 1ms, which worked previously).